# Nextjs <Image/> doesn't work same as <img/> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am watching nextjs tutorial and I need to add image like on the tutorial video. But when I add `<Image/>` tag it doesn't work same as the tutorial. Than I tried normal `<img/>` tag and it worked.

Here is my tage for `<Image/>`

```
<Image
   src="https://links.papareact.com/f90"
   width:{150}
   height:{40}
   style={{ objectFit: "contain"}}
   className="cursor-pointer"
   alt="amazon logo"
  />
```

[image: This is output for Image tag]

Here is my tage for `<img/>`

```
<img
  src="https://links.papareact.com/f90"
  style={{ objectFit: "contain", width: "150px", height: "40px" }}
  className="cursor-pointer"
  alt="amazon logo"
 />
```

[image: This is output for img tag]

Why these two doesn't work same each other ?
How can I use `<Image />` tag like the second output

Comment: Rather than showing us screenshots, show us the difference in the rendered markup. Is the HTML different? Are different styles being applied?

Comment: Everything same. Only difference is like on the screenshots there is no spaces around image with`<Image/>` tag. and `<img/>` looks fitter.

Comment: By the way the problem might be object fit attribute. It might not work with.  `<Image />` tag but also I dont't know why is not working.

Comment: If you see that style rule on the image element in the browser, that's not the problem.  I suggest you show us anyway. We might see something you don't, and there's not much we can help with otherwise.